# How to save a nested resource in ActiveRecord using a single form (Ruby on Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-resources

I have two entities with a many-to-one relationship. User has many Addresses. When creating a User I want the form to also create a single Address. The entities are nested.

**Approach 1:**
The code below works, but only saves the User, no associated Address.

Reading around, I thought that the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` would automatically save the address. I'm not sure, but it may be that this isn't working because the parameters I'm getting into the Controller don't actually appear to be nested, ie. they look like:

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"test"}, "address"=>{"address"=>"test"}
```

Rather than being nested like this:

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"test", "address"=>{"address"=>"test"} }
```

I assume this could be due to something wrong in my form, but I don't know what the problem is...

**Approach 2:**
I have also tried changing the controller - implementing a second private method, `address_params`, which looked like `params.require(:address).permit(:address)`, and then explicitly creating the address with `@user.address.build(address_params)` in the `create` method.

When tracing through this approach with a debugger the Address entity did indeed get created successfully, however the `respond_to do` raised an ArgumentError for reasons I don't understand ("respond_to takes either types or a block, never both"), and this rolls everything back before hitting the save method...

[EDIT] - The `respond_to do` raising an error was a red herring - I was misinterpreting the debugger. However, the transaction is rolled back for reasons I don't understand.

**Questions:**

1. Is one or the other approach more standard for Rails? (or maybe neither are and I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something)
2. What am I doing wrong in either / both of these approaches, and how to fix them so both User and Address are saved?

**Relevant code below** (which implements Approach 1 above, and generates the non-nested params as noted):

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

**address.rb**

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, address_attributes: [:address])
    end

end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= fields_for(user.address.build) do |u| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= u.label :address %>
      <%= u.text_field :address %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

After making the changes suggested by @Ren, I can see that the parameters look more like what I would've expected for nested resources:

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"test", "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"address"=>"test"}}}
```

However, when trying to save the user, the transaction is still rolled back for reasons I don't understand. The output I get from the users.new page is:

> 2 error prohibited this user from being saved:
>
> Addresses user must exist
>
> Addresses user can't be blank

However, using byebug, after the `@user = User.new(user_params)` call, things look as I would expect them:

```
(byebug) @user
#<User id: nil, name: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
(byebug) @user.addresses
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Address id: nil, user_id: nil, address: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

Obviously the user.id field is not set until the record is written to the DB, so equally the address.user_id field cannot be set until user is saved, so maybe this is caused by some sort of incorrect ordering when ActiveRecord is saving to the database? I will continue to try to understand what's going on by debugging with byebug...

**UPDATE 2:**

Using `rails console` to test, saving User first and then adding the Address works (both records get written to the DB, although obviously in 2 separate transactions):

```
> user = User.new(name: "consoleTest")
> user.save
> user.addresses.build(address: "consoleTest")
> user.save
```

Saving only once at the end results in the same issues I'm seeing when running my program, ie. the transaction is rolled back for some reason:

```
> user = User.new(name: "consoleTest")
> user.addresses.build(address: "consoleTest")
> user.save
```

As far as I can tell from debugging with `rails console`, the only difference between the state of `user.addresses` in these two approaches is that in the first `address.user_id` is already set, since the `user.id` is already known, while as in the second, it is not. So this may be the problem, but from what I understand, the `save` method should ensure entities are saved in the correct order such that this is not a problem. Ideally it would be nice to be able to see which entities `save` is trying to write to the DB and in which order, but debugging this with byebug takes me down an ActiveRecord rabbit-hold I don't understand at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**:  As opposed to previous versions, Rails 5 now makes it required that in a parent-child `belongs_to` relationship, the associated id of the parent must be present by default upon saving the child.  Otherwise, there will be a validation error. And apparently it isn't allowing you to save the parent and child all in one step... So for the below solution to work, a fix would be to add `optional: true` to the `belongs_to` association in the Address model:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

See my answer in a question that branched off from this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39688720/5531936

---

It seems to me that you are mixing up the singular and plural of your `address` object in such a way that is not in accordance with Rails.  If a User **has many** addresses, then your Model should show `has_many :addresses` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` should have `addresses`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

and your strong params in your controller should have `addresses_attributes`:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, addresses_attributes: [:id, :address])
end
```

Now if you want the User to just save One Address, then in your form you should have available just one instance of a nested address:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.addresses.build
end
```

By the way it seems like your form has `fields_for` when it should be `f.fields_for`:

```
<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |u| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= u.label :address %>
     <%= u.text_field :address %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

I highly recommend that you take a look at the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) documentation on Nested Forms, section 9.2.  It has a similar example where a Person `has_many` Addresses.  To quote that source:

> When an association accepts nested attributes fields_for renders its
>   block once for every element of the association. In particular, if a
>   person has no addresses it renders nothing. A common pattern is for
>   the controller to build one or more empty children so that at least
>   one set of fields is shown to the user. The example below would result
>   in 2 sets of address fields being rendered on the new person form.
>
> ```
> def new
>   @person = Person.new
>   2.times { @person.addresses.build}
> end
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I've made the changes you suggested and feels like I am getting closer. Unfortunately it's still not quite working. Using byebug after creating the User I can see both User and Addresses are created: `#<User id: nil, name: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>` and `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Address id: nil, user_id: nil, address: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>`. However, the transaction is rolled back when `save` is called. I'm trying to trace through with byebug, but am ending up in a rabbit hole of ActiveRecord core classes...

Comment: I found an error in your Address model.  See edited answer.  hopefully that will solve things..

Comment: Sorry, I think that was just a typo in the question, it wasn't actually like that in my source. As a test, I made the simplest nested example I could just using models (without any of the forms or controllers) and tried creating and saving using rails console, and it still isn't working...! I asked this as a separate question since there were a wide range of thinks wrong with my first attempt in this one, and it's much easier explained with a fresh example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687247/rails-activerecord-saving-nested-models-is-rolled-back)

Comment: ahh ok, was so close to solving this haha

Comment: When (or if!) I find the root cause, which I believe will be the same problem as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687247/rails-activerecord-saving-nested-models-is-rolled-back), then I'll comment / edit your answer and mark it as correct, since you've corrected a bunch of things that were wrong with what I was doing above!

Comment: updated my answer with the findings of the other question.  I haven't used Rails 5 yet so i had no idea..