# Rails ActiveRecord: Saving nested models is rolled back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
```

I've created the simplest example I can think of to demonstrate the issue:

**parent.rb**

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

**child.rb**

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

**Create parent, save, create child, save (works)**

Using `rails console`, creating a new parent, then saving, then building a child from the parent, then saving the parent, works fine:

```
irb(main):004:0> parent = Parent.new
=> #<Parent id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> parent.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `parents` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-09-25 13:05:44', '2016-09-25 13:05:44')
   (3.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):006:0> parent.children.build
=> #<Child id: nil, parent_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):007:0> parent.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Parent Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `parents`.* FROM `parents` WHERE `parents`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `children` (`parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '2016-09-25 13:05:52', '2016-09-25 13:05:52')
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

**Create parent, create child, save (doesn't work)**

However, if I try to create a new parent, then build the child *without* saving the parent, and finally save the parent at the end, the transaction fails and is rolled back:

```
irb(main):008:0> parent = Parent.new
=> #<Parent id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):009:0> parent.children.build
=> #<Child id: nil, parent_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):010:0> parent.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

Can anyone explain why, and how to fix?

**UPDATE**

Creating both parent and child, then saving does work if you pass `validate: false`, so this points to the issue being validation of the child failing, because it requires the parent_id to be set - but presumably the child validation must be running **before** the parent is saved then, or it wouldn't fail?

```
irb(main):001:0> parent = Parent.new
=> #<Parent id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> parent.children.build
=> #<Child id: nil, parent_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> parent.save(validate: false)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO `parents` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-09-25 15:02:20', '2016-09-25 15:02:20')
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO `children` (`parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3, '2016-09-25 15:02:20', '2016-09-25 15:02:20')
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

**UPDATE 2**

It also works using `save` (without the `validation: false`) if I remove the `belongs_to :parent` line from `child.rb`, since then no validation takes place that `parent_id` is valid before being persisted - however, then you lose ability to get at the parent from the child (via `child.parent`). You can still get to the child from the parent (via `parent.child`).

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try `.save!` and then report what it says?

Comment: @DanRubio `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Children parent must exist` - then there's a huge stack trace, but the top line is `from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in 'raise_validation_error'`

Comment: I've also just tried save!(validate: false) which works! I will update the question with this info as well...

Comment: Can you check your Gemfile and post the exact version of rails you are using?

Comment: @Dinesh `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'`

Comment: Oh, and in case it helps, ruby version is `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]` and `bundle` shows `Using rails 5.0.0.1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with this:

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, optional: true
end
```

After doing some research I discovered that Rails 5 now requires an associated id to be present in the child **by default**.  Otherwise Rails triggers a validation error.

Check out this [article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) for a great explanation and the relevant [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937)

...and the official Rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) make a very brief mention of it:

> 4.1.2.11 :optional
>
> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the
>   associated object won't be validated. By default, this option is set
>   to false.

So you can turn off this new behavior by adding `optional: true` after the `belongs_to` object.

So in your example you would have to create/save Parent first before building the child, or use `optional: true`

Comment: thanks, `optional: true` is working now in the dummy example I posted, I will update my main app in a minute and feedback if that is also working! Seems odd to me that this is now the default behaviour given that it seems pretty standard to create parent/child relationships at the same time from a single form (at least, there seem to be quite a lot of tutorials about it).

Comment: @ren I was thinking about the same solution. But, In this scenario where we want to save children with parent, this looks like a bug in rails 5.

Comment: So this worked with my main app too. I was also validating relationship presence myself with `validates_existence_of` on the 'foreign key' fields, which I obviously needed to get rid of too, since it seems all the validation (both parent and child) is occurring before either entity is actually being persisted to the DB. I expected in such a scenario that rails would validate the parent, persist the parent, validate the child, persist the child. Although I suppose validating all at the start makes sense. But validating 'foreign key' fields before the parent is persisted to DB doesn't seem to...

Comment: i agree it's weird behavior and looking like a bug that affects nested forms

Answer (score 1):

Both sides of the association need to be marked with `inverse_of`. See [Rails Guides: Bi-directional Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations).

`inverse_of` lets Rails know what association keeps the opposite reference from the other model.  If set, when you call `parent.children.build`, the new Child will have its `#parent` set automatically. That lets it pass the validation check!

Example:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :children
end

> parent = Parent.new
 => #<Parent id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
> parent.children.build
 => #<Child id: nil, parent_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
> parent.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "parents" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2016-09-26 00:46:42 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-26 00:46:42 UTC]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "children" ("parent_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["parent_id", 2], ["created_at", 2016-09-26 00:46:42 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-26 00:46:42 UTC]]
   (1.8ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

Comment: I don't think that :inverse_of would work with a polymorphic association. In that case, the better answer is to use :optional => true